# Curl error: Maximum (20) redirects followed

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

While trying to CURL to myntra it's giving error. I am trying to get extract details by DOMDOCUMENT, but it's giving the same error:

> Maximum (20) redirects followed

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $url = 'http://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/nike/nike-men-black-dart-12-msl-running-shoes/1547908/buy?src=search&uq=false&q=nike&p=1';
        $ch  = curl_init($url);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: test=cookie"));

        $cl  = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
        {
                echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
                echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_errorno($ch);
        }else{
           $dom = new DOMDocument();
           $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
           print_r($xpath);            
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add some cookies file.

Like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
```

It should work.

Comment: indeed it does, no idea why though

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/nike/nike-men-black-dart-12-msl-running-shoes/1547908/buy?src=search&uq=false&q=nike&p=1';
$ch  = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
$request_headers = [
                'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8;',
                'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",

            ];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$cl  = curl_exec($ch);
$h = curl_getinfo($ch);
$e = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($cl);
```

Sometimes you must need to send the request headers and then decode as per encoding.

Comment: i am getting response now, but how to get <script> tag data from it? can u suggest something?

Comment: That is a completely different aspect like how you want to parse.. What  do you want to get from `<script>` tag

Comment: You need to study the structure of the code on myntra and then write method for that..

Comment: i am trying like this :                                                                                        $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML($cl);
           $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
           $product_name = $xpath->query('//h1[@class="pdp-title"]'); but no getting the values, while seeing network activity on firebug i am getting 500 internal server error

Answer (score -5):

Use CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS option for this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS , 1000);
```

I hope it works, Good Luck!!

Comment: That's rarely the cure. The loop is the problem and it won't get fixed by looping more laps. Often a case of cookies.

Comment: while using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS , 1000);, it keeps loading, no results i got yet !!!

Comment: remove header `'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',`

Comment: This isn't just not the cure, it's bad advice (-1). If it is stuck in a redirect loop (it will already be doing the default of 10 or so) then increasing the max redirects will just loop more before failing again, giving the appearance of a denial of service attack against the scrape target. The OP is already not respecting the Robots.txt protocol, and this makes that situation worse.